# Как нормально запустить SSL сертификат на node js

Tags: https, node.js

имеется SSL сертификат(достоверенный) и приложение на ноде:
`var fs=require("fs");
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var redis=require("redis");
var client = redis.createClient();
var mysql=require("mysql");
var app = express();
client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});
var options = {
key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/key.pem', 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.crt', 'utf8')
};
var server=https.createServer(options, function(req, res){
 console.log("https сервер запущен");
}).listen(9099);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);`
Пробовал запустить код, но выдавало ошибку:                                                          `crypto.js:132
  if (options.cert) c.context.setCert(options.cert);                         ^
Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line`
Нашел решение через выполнение:
 `openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -keyout key.pem -out csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out server.crt`
И                                                                                 `var options = {
      key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem', 'utf8'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.crt', 'utf8')
   };`
Теперь все запускается, но выдает сообщение о том, что сертификат недостоверный(необходимо подтвердить действие перехода)+его еще и скачать нужно на компьютер, дабы браузер открыл. Может кто сталкивался с подобным, что можно сделать?

Comment: как вы получили этот сертификат?

Comment: Его бесплатно предоставляет хостинг при покупке доменов

Comment: а что у вас за хочтинг? кто у них провайдер сертификатов? вы можете получить бесплатный сертификат от https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: Не знаю я использовал nginx для ноды и туда в конфиге указал сертификты без проблем. Тут больше вопрос как правильно сформировать сертификаты что-бы они были валидными, не перепутать ничего